# Retrive data posted by ajax datatype=json with php

Tags: php, jquery, json

I send a data like page number to a php page to do some things. Then php code sends me an array. To get php array in jQuery I used json. It has returned an array but in php page it can't get the page number that I send?

**jQuery:**

```
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/pagging_employs_list.php',
        data: 'id=testdata',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result[0]);
        },
      });
```

**PHP:**

```
    $params = json_decode($_POST['id']);
    .
    .
    // here that i want to use data, not working an i vant get id value

    $array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
    echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: You don't need the `json_decode()` call on the server side, since the data is not sent as JSON string. The notation `dataType: 'json'` defines that the _response_ the server _sends_ will be a JSON string. The data sent to the server by that AJAX call is a plain form post. So you can simply access that parameter by `$_POST['id']` if you send the data like that instead: `data: {id: 'testdata'}`

Comment: i tried but still not working :

Comment: this is my jquery now:

Comment: `$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/pagging_employs_list.php',
        data: 'id=testdata',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        }
      }); `

Comment: and php code is now:

Comment: `$params = $_POST['page'];
    .
    .
    // here that i want to use data, not working an i vant get id value

    $array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
    //echo json_encode($array);
    echo $params;`

Comment: Please do not post additional information in comments here. There is an `edit` button below your question. _Use it._

Comment: Also that ajax code you now posted clearly shows that you did not follow what I explained in my first comment.

Comment: yes this is copy mistake i also used `data: {id: 'testdata'},` but not working. was it your mean?

Comment: Why is it suddenly `$_POST['page']`?!? `id` and `page` are two different things.

Comment: i'm sorry, again its copy mistake. i changed it to `id` but not working? when i remove `dataType: 'json'` from my jquery code its working but array not working! :(

Comment: This is getting more and more unreadable. Once more: please post your code in your question, use the `edit` button for that. We need to see your current code.

Comment: jquery code is: `$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'php/pagging_employs_list.php',
            data: {id: 'testdata'},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });` and now my php code to return data is : `$params = $_POST['id']; echo $params;` it's wery simple but i dont know why with `dataType: 'json' ` not working!

Comment: i find it .... if i remove `dataType: 'json' ` from jquery and use `var dataObj = JSON.parse(result); ` to get array from php and alert `dataObj[0])` for array working. also for sended data `data: {id: 'testdata'}` working too. but how can i send a data dynamicaly? for example i have a page number stor in `pagenum` var this code not working `data: {id: pagenum}` how can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST` cannot be used here because it only works with url encoded data.

You need to read from stdin, for example

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://stdin'));
```